# Positioning DIVs to the sides of a centered container

Tags: css, positioning, css-position

I have a main container DIV for the content of my page, that is horizontally centered:

HTML:

```
<div id="master_container">
  .. my content here ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#master_container {width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Client wants to have adverts at both sides of the page, outside of the master_container. I tried various CSS to try and position those divs but when window is resized, they overlap with the master_container. Also, I am asked to have them float when the page is scrolled.

Can anyone please direct me to the correct solution? Thanks in advance...

Comment: So what is to happen to the adverts when the resizing doesnt have room for them? They wrap over master_container at the moment but that's not desired... are they supposed to just hide?

Comment: they are supposed to hide just like what happens when there is not enough room for the master_container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**>> [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/qbKzx/) <<**

[Note that I used a 700px width for `#master_container`]

### 1. Positioning

Most important CSS is the styling and positioning of the adverts, which I have given the class `.advertis`:

```
.advertis {
    position: fixed; /*creates floating effect */
    top: 20px; /* divs will always stay 20px from top */
    width: 220px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: white;
    border: #ccc 1px solid;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

#left {
    margin-left: -613px; left: 50%; /* positioning of left ads */
} 

#right {
    margin-right: -613px; right: 50%; /* positioning of right ads */
}
```

I can hear you wonder: how do I calculate the margin that I need? Simple:

Get width of `#master_container` (*including padding*) = `720px`. Divide it by `2` = `360px`. Add the width of the ad (*including padding and border*) = `242px`. `240px + 360px = 600px`. Add the space that you want to have between the container and the ad = `11px` (in my case).

`242px (full width of ad) + 360px (half of container) + 11px (space between ad and container) = 613px (margin needed)`

### 2. Hiding when window too small

Now you want to hide the ads when they don't fit in the window any more. You have options for that:

- Media Queries
- jQuery (or JavaScript or another of its libraries)

In the first jsFiddle I have used media queries (**not** supported by all browsers). In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/qbKzx/3/) Fiddle, I have used jQuery to get the same effect.

```
function widthCheck() {
    var ads = $(".advertis");

    if ($(window).width() < 1225) {
        ads.hide();
    }
    else {
        ads.show();
    }
}

widthCheck(); // Execute onLoad

$(window).resize(function(){
    widthCheck();  // Execute whenever a user resizes the window
});
```

​

It's up to you to choose which one you want to use. I'll list a few pros and cons, so you can choose for yourself.

**Pros media queries:**

- modern, progressive
- works, even when JS is disabled

**Cons:**

- not supported by all browsers

**Pros jQuery:**

- supported by (as good as) all browsers

**Cons:**

- does not work when JS is disabled
- not as progressive as media queries

Comment: I have changed my answer to this one, as this solutions works exactly as I wanted. Also, +1 for the use of @media for disappearing ads.. and +1 for the explanation on calculating the margin..

Comment: @Emin I have edited the answer and added the possibility of jQuery!

Comment: Ok stop bram! You'll hurt yourself! :)) I really do appreciate your answer. It's "teaching" rather than convincing to copy/paste... And I did learn from it. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Emin That's what I try to do or promote: get people to learn rather than to copy-paste things. Glad it works and that I could help!

Answer (score 1):

How about that:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/insertusernamehere/Ct5BM/

#### HTML

```
<div id="master_container">
    <div class="ad left">Advertising</div>
    <div class="ad right">Advertising</div>
    The real content …
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
<style>

    body {
        width:      100%;

    }

    #master_container {
        position:   relative;
        width:      960px;
        height:     500px;
        margin:     0 auto;
        border:     1px solid red;
    }

    div.ad {
        position:   absolute;
        top:        0px;
        width:      200px;
        height:     400px;
        margin:     0px 0px 0px 0px;
        border:     1px solid blue;
    }

    div.ad.left {
        left:       -220px;
    }

    div.ad.right {
        right:      -220px;
    }

</style>
```

#### Edit: How it works

When you position the main element relative it's not taken out of its flow within its content but it opens a new space for positioning, z-indexes etc. So a child element within this container which has an absolute position is related to the position of its parent. So in this example the "ad" element has a width if 200px and with left -220px it's moved outside the container on the left side with a little "margin" added.

Comment: *Client wants to have adverts at **both** sides of the page* +  *have them float when the page is scrolled*

Comment: I didn't get the "float" part. You mean they should be visible all the time when scrolling? Like being fixed at their vertical position?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an ad on the left and right side.

Comment: Could you use JavaScript for that? Like `onscroll` changes the `top` value of both ad containers? Would be like 4 lines with jQuery.

Comment: It seems that the OP **must** use JS, because he can't have both `fixed` and `absolute` positioning at the same time

Comment: Actually this is what I was trying to say, because I don't see any other solution. ;)

Comment: Ok thank you all for the contribution. Basically the code given by @insertusernamehere works, but again, when the browser is resized, the advert div overlaps with the master_container. It has to be a part of the whole page, so basically stays whereever it is even if the browser is resized. 

Also, the ad divs are positioned from the right/left of the browser window boundaries, what I need is to position them from the right/left of where the master_container starts/finishes. I think the solution is to use JS as zoltan suggests?

Comment: What do you mean by 'overlap'? The ads will never overlap with the master container because they are positioned left and right to the master container. But they will get invisible when the browser window is too small.

Comment: I made a mistake while implementing your code. works like a charm.. Thank you very much.. But can you explain the logic why are left/right -220px?

Comment: I added a short explanation to the answer. Didn't have time to add it right away. Was kinda in a hurry. :)